# regex AFTER grouping construct not being set correctly?

Tags: regex, nant

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829412/how-to-change-one-line-in-a-file-using-nant) thread. I've tried to replace the set the current version of my project in my NAnt script.

Here's my Replace snippet

```
<target name="Replace">
    <loadfile file="${SetVersionCpp.File}" property="h.file.content" />
    <regex
      input="${h.file.content}"
      pattern="(?'BEFORE'[.\s]*)${LineBegining}\s*[\s\d,]*\r\n(?'AFTER'[.\s]*)" />
    <echo
      file="${SetVersionCpp.File}"
      message="${BEFORE}${LineBegining} ${ReplaceWith}
      ${AFTER}"
      append="false"
      verbose="true" />
</target>
```

Which I call on this file

```
#define FILEVER 0, 2, 0, 3
#define PRODUCTVER 0, 2, 0, 3
#define STRFILEVER     "00.02.00.03\0"
#define STRPRODUCTVER  "00.02.00.03\0"
```

with the following parameters

```
<property name="SetVersionCpp.File" value="${baseline.dir}\VersionNo.h" />
<property name="LineBegining" value="#define FILEVER" />
<property name="ReplaceWith" value="${FileVersion}" />
```

Based on the output, the AFTER variable is not capturing the rest of the file for some reason.  This is what I get:

```
[#define FILEVER 0, 2, 0, 30

]
```

*I put it in brackets so that the whitespace got correctly formatted

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I can't tell from your snippet what line endings are being used in your file, but \r\n won't match unix line endings. Are you sure you are using windows style text files?

Comment: I'm using Wwindows. I just tried \r and \n instead of \r\n and it did not change the outcome.

Comment: If I remove the classes from the `pattern` as such, `(?'BEFORE'.*)${LineBegining}\s*[\s\d,]*\r\n(?'AFTER'.*)`, I get a the second line included in the result and inconsistent line endings

Comment: I've fixed it by setting `options` to `Singleline`. For another 6 hours however, I can't answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it by setting the `options` to `Singleline` so that `.` would match line breaks and by removing the classes from the groups:

```
<regex
  input="${h.file.content}"
  options="Singleline"
  pattern="(?'BEFORE'.*)${LineBegining}\s*[\s\d,]*\r\n(?'AFTER'.*)" />
```